# Display pictures one after the other

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xaml, listbox

I have a question concerning listbox or something similar that could help me. I read lots of pictures from an json and I display them into a list box, I made the image as it’s could fit the page and I scroll them horizontally ,so that I can display them as an album of pictures.

The problem is when you scroll in a listbox, the scroll just keeps going it doesn’t stop, what I want to do is I can display only one picture each, and the scroll stops each time a display a picture.

Do you have any idea how can I do this? Thank you!

Comment: well, i´d say that a listbox is not your control of choice over here.
if you insist on using a listbox, disable the out-of-the-box scrolling behavior and override it with your own logic.

Comment: Do you have any idea ,on what i can use instead of a listbox,where I can bind my data into something that could display each image apart ?

Comment: maybe the out of the box scrolling could work ,could you post an answer of this,an example or something like this plz

Comment: you could catch flick gestures (that result in a fast scrolling) before they result in scrolling and use the underlying panel´s IScrollInfo Interface to scroll to a specific position. just an idea, but may work.

Comment: Thanks for the help,i'll try to work in your idea ,and wait for another suggestions ,thanks another time :)

Comment: The Pivot or Panorama controls are what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked at the [RadSlideView](http://www.telerik.com/help/windows-phone/radslideview-overview.html) from telerik?

> RadSlideView is a unique control that allows you to navigate through a
>   sequence of items slide-by-slide. It works in data-bound mode only and
>   offers exceptional performance with smooth transitions among slides.

Comment: that seems good stuff ,but i'm wondering if there is an open source solution ?

Comment: Yeah, it's not opensource but a lic. cost $99 and comes with source.

Comment: yeah i'm looking at the other functionalities ,cause I can’t pay 99$ just for the slider, beside this i've tried the trial version with the slider ,that's work great,but the graphs ,there is open source stuff similar to what they propose

Answer (score 0):

It may not be pretty but here's one solution -

```
Add a slider and use it instead of scroll-bar
Have just one image control
Set Slider's Minimum = 0 and Maximum = number of images
Set Slider's TickFrequency="1", IsMoveToPointEnabled="True" and IsSnapToTickEnabled="True"
Change your image when slider's value changes
```

Additionally, you can handle scroll events to ++ or -- the slider's value